# VSCode module.exports autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Using latest VSCode version 1.30.2 and it doesn't see the functions that are inside the exported module.

this is in model.js

```
var userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', usersSchema);
userModel.isUsernameTaken = isUsernameTaken;
module.exports = userModel;

function isUsernameTaken(username) {
    return userModel.findOne({username:username});
}
```

and in app.js

```
var userModel = require('./model');
```

Now upon typing userModel. in app.js I should see a suggestion for autocompletion of isUsernameTaken, but it's not there and also not any of the functions declared in model are "visible". However if I type the exact function name (case-sensitive). (ex: userModel.isUserNameTaken(etc)) it works. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by changing in model.js

```
module.exports.default = userModel;
```

and then in another file:

```
var userModel = require(./model).default;
```

Now intellisense works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `userModel.isUsernameTaken(username)`, what you are really saying is `mongoose.model('userModel', usersSchema).isUsernameTaken(username)`, in which this would return as undefined. What you would have to do is make user Model into an object with the `mongoose.model('userModel', usersSchema)` inside of it. Kind of like this:

```
var userModel = function () {
    this.model: mongoose.model('userModel', usersSchema),
    this.isUsernameTaken: (username) => {
        return this.model.findOne({username:username});
    }
};
```

Then if you wanted to access these attributes you could use
`var user = new userModel();` then use `user.isUsernameTaken(/*put username here*/);`. Or if you wanted to access the model alone you could do: `user.model`. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: If my way of doing it is wrong, why does it work in other IDE's (ex: JetBrains WebStorm) and why does my functions works as they should when they are called from the app.js file. It's just the autocomplete that doesn't really work. I have tried your code, but it doesn't work for me. It says (expected ";"). I changed the code and replaced ":" with "=", so the errors are now gone, but the whole concept of the code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

For me, (although not in the context of mongoose), I was having the same issue. autocomplete was not working and `module.exports` was also not turning into green color in VSCode. The fix for me was that I accidentally put an ES6 import in the file:

```js
import config from 'config' // wrong way of importing
// my code
module.exports = {
  myObj
}
```

I simply changed it to use `require`

```js
const config = require('config')
```

and it started working properly