# Vs code, no autocomplete with javascript (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So I've been working with discord.js for a little while but whenever I type any discord related function/object, the intellisense proposition are totally unrelated or straight up missing. It's quite annoying and couldn't find why. Though it seems to work in the main file (index.js)

**otherfile.js:**

[image]

**index.js:**

[image]

What could the problem be?

Comment: If the `discord.js` module isn't exported into the file then VS code cannot detect what `Client` is.

Comment: The only thing that could help you a bit is **[GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/)**, which is GitHub's AI code-autocompletion. But you have to register for it and if you're lucky you'll get access

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. What fixed it for me?
Actually switching to TypeScript. I set the client Type, to Client from discord.js, and now it is working. I know, it is not the easiest fix, but for sure one that works.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Coming from c# and java background I have no idea how to apply your fix. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. Comparable to C++ and C. 
In In typescript you can set types for variables. By doing this, you can use intellisense in all files. [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Answer (score -1):

This should pretty much fix the issue

> In other files, try adding this piece of code
>
> ```js
> const { Client } = require("discord.js")
>
> module.exports = {
> /**
>   * 
>   * @param {Client} client
>   */
> }
> ```

You can import other classes like `Message` with the respective paramater (for eg: `message`).

If you're still confused, type `client.` and press **CTRL + SPACEBAR** at the same time. This will bring the drop down menu of  options.

Comment: Discord.js is already imported, I think I should have mentioned the autocomplete doesn't work inside a `module.exports ={}` but works fine outside of it. It's similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506309/vscode-module-exports-autocomplete-doesnt-work) but I couldn't fix it or find anything else. Seeing how it doesn't work either on discord tutorials youtube videos I assumed it was just "dumb"

Comment: Put the `@param {Client} client` inside the `module.exports = {}`

Comment: There, I have edited it